# logging configuration with log4j.properties, cannot exclude package from logging to console

Tags: log4j

i have the following log4j.properties file. what i want to do is log everything at the level INFO or above to the console. however, for anything that falls in the demo.* package, i want to log everything at the DEBUG level to a file. my log4j.properties below does not seem to work. what happens is that any DEBUG message from demo.* still gets output to the console. any idea what i am doing wrong?

how can i exclude demo.* from logging to the console?

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, C
log4j.logger.demo=DEBUG, R1

log4j.appender.C=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.C.target=System.err
log4j.appender.C.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.C.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n

log4j.appender.R1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R1.File=output.log
log4j.appender.R1.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.R1.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.R1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, never mind. i solved it by setting the threshold of the console appender.

```
log4j.appender.C.threshold=INFO
```